# Massive selectors in semantic bootstrap with sass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

When you are using @extend in sass, it will append your selector to every place where the extended element is used, [like so](http://sassmeister.com/gist/dcd02bb98aad8892e75b). It's correctly valid, and expected behaviour. Now, bootstrap is really robust framework. In "standard" workflow you would create a button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-button">Delete</button>

.delete-button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

However, using meaningful class names is encouraged, likeso:

```
<button type="button" class="delete-button">Delete</button>

.delete-button {
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-danger;

    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Well, this creates a new problem. Because bootstrap has to consider every combination possible (button in buttongroup, class applied to specific type of tag, etc.), the new class will be applied to ~150 different combinations.

Example foo.scss:

```
//For this purpose includes whole package 
@import "bootstrap-custom";

.delete-button {
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .btn-danger;
}
```

Resulting css: https://gist.github.com/Misiur/2b6ea7e631e7c1e0a444

After a while (like multiple buttons) selectors are reaching completely unacceptable lenghts (I only noticed that after my devtools hang themselves and died). Even with tools like uncss things get out of hand pretty quickly.

How should I deal with situation like that? Smacss helps with building reasonable architecture, but still there are always a lot of specific variants.

Thank you

Comment: An ~8000 line gist is excessive.  No one is going to go through that.

Comment: You want the real answer?  Either "don't use Bootstrap" or "rewrite Bootstrap to not be retarded".  Take your pick.

Comment: The way the CSS in Bootstrap is written is sometimes extremely deeply nested. This will not working well with `@extend`ing, as you have seen. Try doing `@extend .form` and you'll run into a similar problem. If you are planning on relying on `@extend`, you should use a framework that is written with more of an object-oriented CSS aproach.

Comment: Perhaps give up on `@extend`-ing `.btn` and instead aim for `class="btn delete-button"`.